# Get InputStream from Vert.x HttpServerRequest

Tags: java, http, vert.x

I have a Java client-server application with Vert.x. The client sends file to the server and the server gets is in a HttpServer request. I need to save this file on the server.

How can I get the the input stream from the request?

Comment: You mean like this? http://vertx.io/core_manual_groovy.html#reading-data-from-the-request-body

Comment: Not at all. I meant that I need something to pass to outputStream.write() in order to save the file. 

It is possible to use byte[] in output stream, that's why the problem was solved by getBytes() method.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this is what you want: since you could get a instance of HttpServerrequest, why not add an uploadHandler, just like the following code from Vert.x doc?

```
request.uploadHandler { upload -> 
    upload.streamToFileSystem "uploads/${upload.filename()}"
}
```

In this way, you also could save the file on the server.